# Pandas/Dask - Very long time to write to file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I have a few files. The big one is ~87 million rows. I have others that are ~500K rows. Part of what I am doing is joining them, and when I try to do it with Pandas, I get memory issues. So I have been using Dask. It is super fast to do all the joins/applies, but then it takes 5 hours to write out to a csv, even if I know the resulting dataframe is only 26 rows.

I've read that some joins/applies are not the best for Dask, but does that mean it is slower using Dask? Because mine have been very quick. It takes seconds to do all of my computations/manipulations on the millions of rows. But it takes forever to write out. Any ideas how to speed this up/why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dask Parallel Processing or try writing into `Parquet` file instead of `CSV` as Parquet operation is very fast with Dask

Comment: Still took 3.5 hours to write to parquet. Plus I need it in a csv and don't know how to convert. It says ~10,000 tasks/81 partitions -- could that be an issue?

Comment: If you will use Dask Parallel Processing then it wont take `3.5hrs`. Or else you can use `concurrent.futures` module  for writing data parallelly. Or even `multiprocessing` library can also help in that. Try that once. I will be happy to help if you are stuck with that

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to the documentation? I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`dask` uses lazy evaluation. This means that when you perform the operations, you are actually only creating the processing graph.

Once you try to write your data to a csv file, Dask starts performing the operations.
And that is why it takes 5 hrs, he just needs to process a lot of data.

See https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html for more information on the topic.

One way to speed up the processing would be to increase the parallelism by using a machine with more resources.